# pandas - Copy each row 'n' times depending on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to copy or duplicate the rows of a DataFrame based on the value of a column, in this case `orig_qty`. So if I have a DataFrame and using `pandas==0.24.2`:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': ['2019-04-08', 4, 115.00], 'b': ['2019-04-09', 2, 103.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        d, 
        orient='index', 
        columns=['date', 'orig_qty', 'price']
    )
```

#### Input

```
>>> print(df)
         date  orig_qty   price
a  2019-04-08         4   115.0
b  2019-04-09         2   103.0
```

So in the example above the row with `orig_qty=4` should be duplicated 4 times and the row with `orig_qty=2` should be duplicated 2 times. After this transformation I'd like a DataFrame that looks like:

#### Desired Output

```
>>> print(new_df)
         date  orig_qty  price  fifo_qty
1  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
2  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
3  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
4  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
5  2019-04-09         2  103.0         1
6  2019-04-09         2  103.0         1
```

Note I do not really care about the index after the transformation. I can elaborate more on the use case for this, but essentially I'm doing some FIFO accounting where important changes can occur between values of `orig_qty`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
 new_df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['orig_qty'])].assign(fifo_qty=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[output]

```
         date  orig_qty  price  fifo_qty
0  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
1  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
2  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
3  2019-04-08         4  115.0         1
4  2019-04-09         2  103.0         1
5  2019-04-09         2  103.0         1
```

Comment: Nice solution ;}

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.repeat`

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(df[col], df.orig_qty) for col in df.columns})
```